# Publishing in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, hosting

I am publishing my web app in Azure. The following Error appears:

```
    Error   12  Web deployment task failed. (Could not complete an operation with the specified provider ("dbDacFx") when connecting using the Web Management Service. This can occur if the server administrator has not authorized the user for this operation. dbDacFx http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178034
```

I have tried to un-install all Web Deploy folders in my Program Files Folder but even with nothing opened, it is telling me it is in use and that I can't delete the folder. I have since installed the newest version of Web Deployment.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it can be several things. But I can suggest at first to check if you are creating or altering Database schema behind the application. If so that can be the issue. For instance the user executing the script has no enough rights to perform the desired task.

Please see Azure SQL docs to grant correct sql rights to  the user.